# What is EBS-Snapshot in Amazon AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am confused on forecasted billing charges at my AWS trial account. I did terminated the instances but still its showing like this:

[image: Screenshot of my AWS billing console]

I want to know how I can reduce this cost? What exactly causing the cost?

Answer (score 2):

You created some snapshots (backups) of the EBS disk volume of your instance. These snapshots are not deleted when you delete the instance. You need to go into the EC2 console and find the EBS snapshot section and delete the snapshots if you want to stop getting charged for them.